# Customize Payment/Biling Address Form Fields Opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I want to know where Payment Address Fields are coming from ? Actually I want to modify them.

I tried to edit from:

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/d_quickcheckout/payment_address.tpl
```

But there is no input fields and I am not sure where they are coming from actually.

Reference Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ3Ef.png

Comment: Well, what is the Opencart version ? "d_quickcheckout" may retrive the data from default checkout, did you ever checked ? Most of quickcheckout extensions get the default fields and replace them to hold sql queries steady.

Answer (score 0):

most welcome

i think you are used **d_checkout** extension. i am not know about it.

but default opencart changes his given below.

**Opencart 3x :**

```
Path : catalog\view\theme\default\template\checkout\payment_address.twig
```

**Opencart 2x :**

```
Path : catalog\view\theme\default\template\checkout\payment_address.tpl
```

This is very helpful for you.